# Check vs control. Why is it called "passport control", since it is not "controlling the passports" but it is "checking the passports"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, difference

This is from the BBC web site:

"Hundreds of thousands of travellers arriving in the UK have been told to expect disruption as **passport control** workers begin strikes."

Why is it called **"passport control"** where it is actually checking the passports that they do. Considering the fact that the meaning of "check" and "control" is different, should it not have been called **"passport check"** instead of **"passport control"**?

Comment: It means control of travelers by means of checking their passports.

Answer (score 2):

A 'passport' is a document that identifies a person for the purpose of international travel. With it, you can *pass* through a *port*. Passport control may not 'control' your documents - but it does control who passes through the port.

Don't overthink compound nouns like this. *Border Control* doesn't control borders, either - just the people trying to cross them.